# Leapmotion listener registration fails

Tags: python, oop, leap-motion

I am trying to subclass `Leap.Listener` and register it with the controller:

```
class myLeapMotion(Leap.Listener):
    def __init__(self) :
        controller = Leap.Controller()
        controller.add_listener(self)
```

This raises an exception:

```
TypeError: in method 'Controller_add_listener', argument 2 of type 'Leap::Listener &'
```

How can I pass my subclass as a reference to the controller?

I've thought that `self` would be the listener here but I don't know the right Python syntax to write it.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  It looks you already are passing the object (as `self`).  What is your code not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: You "don't know the syntax to write what"? Leap.Controller.add_listener() is already written as a library method, yes? or no? If yes then follow its doc. If no then post the code for Leap.Controller.

Comment: TypeError: in method 'Controller_add_listener', argument 2 of type 'Leap::Listener &' its my error. Yes its from a library

Comment: @user3306790: What library is it? Perhaps experts on that library can help, but we would need the exact library used.

Comment: hum, it's the library for the Leap Motion sensor. https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/api

Comment: This is really a Leap Motion specific problem; your syntax looks correct to me. I've rewritten your question to reflect that.

Comment: Try to invoke the base class constructor (details in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the objects in Python are passed by reference, so no special syntax is required. Your code should work. In fact, there is NO way to pass it not by reference.

**UPD:** As your question has been changed, it becomes clear that your program fails not because of passing `self` in a wrong way. It is a problem with the library you are using. Try to perform correct initialization for your base class, call `super(myLeapMotion, self).__init__()` before adding a listener. At least [here](https://github.com/openleap/PyLeapMouse/blob/master/PalmControl.py) it is done this way.

**UPD2:** Looks like I am right. [Here](http://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Leap_Motion) the code author does almost exactly the same as you do. The only difference is that he calls `__init__` from the base class.

Comment: Sorry to invalidate your answer; the OP is indeed doing it correctly, but the problem is with the specific SDK being used, not Python syntax.

Comment: Can you explain why the OP is getting an error then? I don't think the question is about "passing by reference", it's how to pass self to another function.

Comment: yes i wanna instantiate a controller type object in an other Listener object, but i need to link him with the Listener obj

Comment: I believe the root of the problem here is overriding the __init__() function without calling the superclass __init__() and then trying to use the object before it is fully initialized. The library in question is a wrapper for a native library, which needs some native objects created and hooked up before it will work.